# Adding nodes to Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, nodes, binary-search-tree

**Disclaimer: This is for an assignment. I am not asking for explicit code answers, only help understanding why my code isn't working.**

I am trying to implement a basic Binary Search Tree, but I am having problems with my `_addNode(...)` function.

Here's the problem. When I walk through my code with the debugger, I notice that leaf nodes are created infinitely on both sides (left and right) so aside from the creation of the root, there is never any point when a leaf node is `NULL`. The problem is that I am asking my program to create a new node whenever it finds a `NULL` value where a leaf would be. Therefore, if there are never any `NULL` values, there will never be any new leaves created, right?

The other issue I'm running into is with my `compare(...)` function. Stepping through it in the debugger shows it to iterate through the function several times, never actually returning a value. When it returns to the calling function, it drops back into the `compare(...)` function and loops infinitely. Again, I don't know why this is happening considering I have valid return statements in each `if` statement.

Here is all the code you'll probably need. If I left something out, let me know and I'll post it.

```
struct Node {
    TYPE         val;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct BSTree {
    struct Node *root;
    int          cnt;
};

struct data {
    int number;
    char *name;
};

int compare(TYPE left, TYPE right)
{
    assert(left != 0);
    assert(right != 0);

    struct data *leftData = (struct data *) left;
    struct data *rightData = (struct data *) right;

    if (leftData->number < rightData->number) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (leftData->number > rightData->number) {
        return 1;
    } else return 0;
}

void addBSTree(struct BSTree *tree, TYPE val)
{
    tree->root = _addNode(tree->root, val);
    tree->cnt++;
}

struct Node *_addNode(struct Node *cur, TYPE val)
{
    assert(val != 0);

    if(cur == NULL) {
        struct Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->val = val;
        return newNode;
    }
    if (compare(val, cur->val) == -1) {
        //(val < cur->val)
        cur->left = _addNode(cur->left, val);
    } else cur->right = _addNode(cur->right, val);

    return cur;
}
```

Edit: Adding the below function(s)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct BSTree *tree = newBSTree();

    /*Create value of the type of data that you want to store*/
    struct data myData1;
    struct data myData2;
    struct data myData3;
    struct data myData4;

    myData1.number = 5;
    myData1.name = "rooty";
    myData2.number = 1;
    myData2.name = "lefty";
    myData3.number = 10;
    myData3.name = "righty";
    myData4.number = 3;
    myData4.name = "righty";

    /*add the values to BST*/
    addBSTree(tree, &myData1);
    addBSTree(tree, &myData2);
    addBSTree(tree, &myData3);
    addBSTree(tree, &myData4);

    /*Print the entire tree*/
    printTree(tree);
    /*(( 1 ( 3 ) ) 5 ( 10 ))*/
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: could you post the code that executes these functions?

Comment: is it typedef struct data *TYPE? (I'm assuming it is just looking at the code).

Comment: You know. I finally copied this code and executed it. I saw no problems, after I explicitly 0 the values in newNode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try setting right and left to `NULL` right after `malloc`:

```
struct Node * newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
newNode->left = NULL;
newNode->right = NULL;
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that.. Thank you. The issue seems to be stemming from `compare(...)` now.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Check this line here (or the corresponding for left):</strike>

cur->right = _addNode(cur->right, val);

If cur->right == 0, it's fine. But if cur->right != 0, the node that was sitting there will be replaced by the return value of _addNode, which ultimately is not a whole branch, but just one node.

I like to explicitly 0-out values in a struct after a malloc using memset(newNode, 0, sizeof(struct Node)). Others might disagree.

Comment: But doesn't the `if(cur == NULL)` operation take care of that? `_addNode(...)` should recognize that `cur->right` is NULL, and then allocate a new node according to the aforementioned `if` statement. ...right?

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right.  I was just looking some more and realized I'm probably wrong here.